# Hostname was not found in DNS cache paypal curl reponse

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to get PayPal transaction history, transaction details and PayPal balance using classic PHP API with CURL. I am running cron for this. I am getting correct response but getting following error also. what can be the reason and possible way to solve it?

```
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Trying 173.0.82.83...
Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0)
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server certificate:
subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal    Production; CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
start date: 2013-08-01 00:00:00 GMT
expire date: 2015-09-18 23:59:59 GMT
issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /nvp HTTP/1.1
Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 163
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

upload completely sent off: 163 out of 163 bytes < HTTP/1.1 200 OK <  Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 06:00:14 GMT
Server Apache is not blacklisted
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Length: 147
< Set-Cookie:X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher_apit%26TIME%3D1857781589; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly < Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT < Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 <
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: On local, I usually get Could not resolve host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com error.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question?  I'm having this same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got solution. I lowered curl version to below 7.33 and It worked for me.